# Are rough stochastic volatility models used on the street for equity derivatives ? (2020)

Tags: derivatives, stochastic-volatility, heston, bates

I'm building out some stochastic vol models for pricing exotic equity derivatives. What's the state of the art on the street?

Comment: No one will tell you what the (true) state of the art is ;)

Comment: We may have come to a stage that we've run out of ideas and are now all using the sledgehammer called machine learning / AI / Neural Networks, which I believe in the olden days were still called regression, gradient descent, optimization and algorithm (much harder terms to sell).